# Child Fantasy book about a girl with special powers inherited from her mother

Tags: story-identification, books

A child Fantasy book about a girl with special powers inherited from her mother (she somehow participated in the plot, but maybe only at the beginning). The powers had something to do with her eyes: I think, she could make people do things by looking at them. Everybody hated her (and was afraid of her). She also had a brother, and they weren't very fond of each other (it may be that he betrayed her later). I don't remember the plot, but she traveled with her brother, and then somehow they got into slavery and had to do some physical work with many other people (who were afraid of the girl). I think it was set in some magic medieval-y world.

I read the book somewhere in 2010 (plus/minus 2 years). I got the book in the library. I think the book was more or less new, I'd say written in 00s. I think on the cover there was a portrait of that girl (it had hardcover). Also it might be that there was a 'D' in the girls name, but I'm really not sure. It might also be part of a series of books.

Please help me to identify the book.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Might this be ***[The Shamer's Daughter](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/590327.The_Shamer_s_Daughter)*** by Lene Kaaberbøl, the first book in the *[The Shamer Chronicles](https://www.goodreads.com/series/43675-the-shamer-chronicles)* series...?

There are four books in the series, with the first having been published in 2000 and the last in 2003.

Here's the Goodreads synopsis for the first book:

> **Dina has unwillingly inherited her mother's gift: the ability to elicit shamed confessions simply by looking into someone's eyes. To Dina, however, these powers are not a gift but a curse. Surrounded by fear and hostility, she longs for simple friendship.**
>
> But when her mother is called to Dunark Castle to uncover the truth about a bloody triple murder, Dina must come to terms with her power--or let her mother fall prey to the vicious and revolting dragons of Dunark.

Someone asked a [story-ID question](https://www.goodreads.com/topic/show/19671422-solved-ya-book-first-read-in-2007-was-about-a-girl-with-magical-powers) about this series on Goodreads, and according to their description, the story is set in medieval times, and the protagonist, Dina, has an older brother and a younger sister, neither of whom have her powers.

> Hi guys wondering if you can help me! I was talking to someone about books that I read when I was younger and I could not remember what they are called! Hopefully someone can help here! **It was a series set in medieval times - the main character was a teenage girl who had powers and so did her mother - her older brother and younger sister did not.** The mother was taken away to a big city. The girl eventually followed. The leader of the place they lived and the guy who ordered the girls mom to be taken away wasere - was called something like Dracon or Draco - something to do with Dragons. She also eventually met her father who also had powers as well but a different type. The girls mother and father had her in order to create an even more powerful being. I think there were about 4 books in the series and I remember reading it in 2007! If anyone can help I would greatly appreciate it!!!

The Goodreads synopsis for the second book in the series, *[The Shamer's Signet](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/590323.The_Shamer_s_Signet)*, mentions a brother named Davin.

> One look into the Shamer's eyes and a person's darkest secrets are revealed
>
> **Dina has recently come into her uncomfortable powers as a Shamer, and now even her brother, Davin, no longer dares to meet her gaze.**
>
> Yet in these dangerous times there are far worse things in store for the young Shamer, who is kidnapped and forced to use her gift as a weapon against innocent people. Dina must get free. Can her brother help her escape?

Comment: Thank you! I have skimmed through the book, but, to be honest, I cannot surely say if this is the book I was talking about. The name of the the main character, her gift and family ring some bells, but the problem is that the cover of the book does not look the way I remembered it. I think I'll wait for some time and then accept your answer.

Comment: @Mrs Robinson - The cover shown in the page linked above was for a 2006 release of the first book. An earlier release had a different cover, as shown [here](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6018307-skammerens-datter). You should only mark this answer as accepted if you think it's the right book though, not just because it's a similar book to the one you described.